# Body Background not displaying

Tags: html, css

So im just trying to simply put the background on my page but nothing is happening.. the background works for another Div on the same page but just not on the body background itself

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>iDeas.com</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css"/>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body background="background.jpg" style="font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;">
  <div id="main_container" >
   <div id="sub_container">
    <div id="header_container">
     <h1 class="uk-h1" style="font-family:'Shadows Into Light',cursive; font-size:110px;margin-left:29%;margin-top:120px;position:absolute;">Welcome To <span style="color:yellow">i</span>Deas.com</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body_container">
     <div id="form_container">
      <div id="form_position" style="position:absolute; margin-left:42%; margin-top:300px;" >
       <div class="uk-form" style="padding:50px 50px 50px 50px; background:url('img/triangle_bg.jpg'); border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post">
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <span class="uk-icon-user uk-icon-small" style="border-radius:5px 0px 0px 3px; padding:11px 14px 14px 17px; background:#E6E6E6;">&nbsp;</span><input autocomplete="off" style="border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; width:230px; height:45px; font-size:16px;" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
         </div>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <span class="uk-icon-lock uk-icon-small" style="border-radius:5px 0px 0px 3px; padding:11px 14px 14px 19px; background:#E6E6E6;">&nbsp;</span><input autocomplete="off" style="border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; width:230px; height:45px; font-size:15px;" type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required="">
         </div>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <input class="uk-button" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" style="width:280px; height:40px; font-size:20px; border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px">
         </div><br> <br>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          &nbsp;Dont have an account..? Register <a href="">Here</a>
         </div> 
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_container">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is in the same folder, no sub directory just to make sure, ive even tried to inline style"background:url..." but that doesnt work either just really confused as to why it doesnt work. I t works on another page i made called test.php as well which had the same image directory and was in the same folder i no problems there

Comment: What is the height of body?

Comment: I think you will add height:100%;  to html and body

Comment: The body has no height? is the body not just the width of the page you are working with? and then the DIVS you must specify the width/ height by yourself? so in short ive not given the <body> tag a height

Comment: Why are you using inline styles?

Comment: Yes im sure it exists -_- i tried it with test.php and it works fine there is nothing wrong with the picture

Comment: I am using inline styles because im using UIKIT and dont want to tamper with the UIKIT css itself any inline css overides any existing code so its much more useful for me to do this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In specifying `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` you're telling browsers to render your page using HTML5. The `background` attribute was deprecated in HTML4 and no longer exists in HTML5.

The best way to do this is to instead include some CSS:

```css
body {
    background: url(background.jpg);
}
```

To include this into your page, you can either use the `style` element, by placing the following into your page's `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Your CSS here. */
</style>
```

Or by creating a separate `.css` file and including it onto your page using the `<link>` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myStylesheet.css">
```

#### Demo

```css
body {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/64x64);
}
```

---

If you really insist on using inline styling, you can instead use the HTML `style` attribute. This is generally bad practice though, as a separate CSS file would be much easier to maintain:

```
<body style="background: background.jpg">
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: I think browsers will still show the background even if the attribute is deprecated.

Comment: @SalmanA they probably shouldn't, seeing as it's using the HTML5 doctype. The `background` attribute was deprecated in HTML4. It doesn't exist in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

To display image in the background using the `<body>` tag, you need to do it like this:
 `<body style="background-image:">`

Comment: Ive tried this its not working you can also do it by doing background="" as i have done, ive tried it both ways

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius its becuase you didnt inculde the url, probebly, if your image is 'background.jpg' then use this code: `background-image:url(background.jpg);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to tamper with uikit css file, you can create your own .css and attach it in your html.

In your case of background not displayed you could use `<html class='uk-height-1-1'>` and `<body class='uk-height-1-1'>`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>iDeas.com</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uikit.min.css"/>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/uikit.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body  style="font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;background:url(http://www.h3dwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Plain_Background_06.jpg)">
  <div id="main_container" >
   <div id="sub_container">
    <div id="header_container">
     <h1 class="uk-h1" style="font-family:'Shadows Into Light',cursive; font-size:110px;margin-left:29%;margin-top:120px;position:absolute;">Welcome To <span style="color:yellow">i</span>Deas.com</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body_container">
     <div id="form_container">
      <div id="form_position" style="position:absolute; margin-left:42%; margin-top:300px;" >
       <div class="uk-form" style="padding:50px 50px 50px 50px; background:url('img/triangle_bg.jpg'); border-radius:2px 2px 2px 2px;">
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post">
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <span class="uk-icon-user uk-icon-small" style="border-radius:5px 0px 0px 3px; padding:11px 14px 14px 17px; background:#E6E6E6;">&nbsp;</span><input autocomplete="off" style="border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; width:230px; height:45px; font-size:16px;" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
         </div>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <span class="uk-icon-lock uk-icon-small" style="border-radius:5px 0px 0px 3px; padding:11px 14px 14px 19px; background:#E6E6E6;">&nbsp;</span><input autocomplete="off" style="border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; width:230px; height:45px; font-size:15px;" type="password" name="password" placeholder="********" required="">
         </div>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          <input class="uk-button" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" style="width:280px; height:40px; font-size:20px; border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px">
         </div><br> <br>
         <div class="uk-form-row">
          &nbsp;Dont have an account..? Register <a href="">Here</a>
         </div> 
        </form>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_container">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```